# How to see all url's loaded using urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

What I am trying to do is basically open a url like so:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

But I want to be able to see every background url that was loaded before getting to http://www.google.com (like all the js files and images). Or it would be even better if I could only capture ones with certain text in the url.

Comment: So you mean that you want to get **a part of the web page**?

Comment: No I'm trying to get all the url's loaded in the background kind of like live http headers does.

Comment: What all gets requested from server depends on the useragent here, It would be 'User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7' in your case. If you manipulate the userAgent to be set as: 'Mozilla/5.0 ...' etc, then it emulates browser and would request more data in the header. You could use netcat command and listen on port. Check this [link](http://krosinski.blogspot.in/2012/05/make-websites-recognise-pythonurllib-as.html).

Comment: So then if the website recognizes me as a real browser how would I programmatically capture url's as the page is loading preferably in a multi-threaded environment?